# В чем различие Business Logic Layer и Data Access Layer

Tags: архитектура

Имеется такая вот архитектура приложения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

DAL реализует два паттерна: Repository и UnitOfWork. Для этого используется ORM. В чем различие между ORM класса, DAL и BLL классами? Или в DAL описываются уже только сущности? Приведите примеры. 
По моим неверным рассуждениям DTO классы получаются такие же и как и ORM. Поправьте меня.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наверное уже не актуально.
Но вот моё мнение:

**BL слой** - в нём производим необходимые манипуляции с данными: обработка, фильтрация. Одним словом всё то, что будет делать наше приложение с данными.

**DAL слой** - предоставляет нам эти самые "данные". При этом мы абстрагируемся от реального источника данных, благодаря интерфейсу DAL. Дело в том что на начальном этапе разработки могут использоваться Mock объекты, на другом подключаться какая-то БД, либо данные получаются из API.

Использование конкретных паттернов не обязательно. У каждого есть свои плюсы и минусы, которые стоит учитывать в зависимости от обстоятельств.

Если в Вы будет использоваться паттерн MVVM для связи между UI и BL, тогда схема связей между моделями будет следующая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: из Вашего ответа мне не понятно в каких случаях стоит использовать промежуточные модели на каждом из уровней и в каких случаях их можно "пробрасывать" выше.

Comment: UI - ViewModel модели?

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk Лучше ничего не пробрасывать. Модели DAL можно использовать в BL, но не в UI. В BL лучше определить новые модели(маппить с моделями из DAL) и связать с UI. Лучше придерживаться принципа единственной ответственности. Т.к. модели верхнего уровня могут содержать дополнительные поля, методы и.т.д. Например реализовывать INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk ViewModel это клей связывающий BL и UI. Там никакой сложной логики быть не должно, сквозной вызов бизнес логики

Comment: т.е. это нормально, что ViewModels передаются в BLL? Я считал всегда, что между BLL & UI обязатольно должно 2 уровня моделей. Один уровень на BLL, а второй ViewModels. Верно ?

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk На счёт разделения моделей еще и между BL и UI - не слышал. Зачем разделять? Почитайте вот тут. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16338888/8069984 . Неплохо описано взаимодействие.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83498/discussion-between-vadim-prokopchuk-and-vasenev-ea).